# Background color of text in CSS?

Tags: css

Any idea how can I make simple text looking like this using CSS?

[image: A button with a cyan background, and black text]

[image: The same button]

[image: A paragraph with the same styles]

I only reached this using `span`

[image: The button using span]

```
a.nav-link span {
    background-color: #00FFF0;
    background-size: 50%; 
    text-decoration-color: black;
    color: black;
    background-position-x: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: you need a wrapper element around, like `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<p>`. There is no plain text selector in CSS

Comment: Added an answer to explain it a bid, but please add some code next time with what you have already tried.

Comment: you need to start learning CSS ...

Comment: @JeroenE ofc you are right. I added the code

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert yeah i have span, but i dont know how style it..

Answer (score -1):

not 100% sure what you are after but...

HTML

```
<p class = "red"> This text has a red background</p>
```

CSS

```
.red{
 background-color:#f00;
}
```

Should do what I think you are asking BTW This is a great place to get some help but normally people will not help you unless you have shown what you have already tried to do, i.e. SO help those who are struggling to solve their own problems but wont help you if you just ask for questions without any proof that you have tried to tackle the problem first. For that people expect to get paid :)